# Why Chrome do not start from launcher after I closed the lid?

Tags: launcher, google-chrome

I've closed the laptop cover, freezing the computer, before dinner.

When I came back, I entered the password and tried to resume the active applications, Chrome and Firefox (from launcher). Chrome didn't start, Firefox did. Weird... Tried to start Chrome from launcher several times, without success. It does seem to start, a window is briefly seen, but minimizes or closes immediately.

Cannot identify the Chrome version because it doesn't even show up. Firefox version is 23.0, Ubuntu version is 12.04 LTS.

What's happening with Chrome? It was working fine before dinner.

Comment: Have you turn it off and on again?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your Chrome window (yeah) is offscreen. It is still there, just that you can't see it. If you want you can run:

```
ps ax | grep -i chrome
```

To see that the process is still there.

So, how to solve this issue. A simple:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ 
unity --reset-icons &disown
```

In the terminal should do the job. If the window still is disappeared, you may need to reboot the system so the changes apply.